# One form and two submit button event handlers making the console blink

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm making a quote generator that stores new quotes passed via the input field and will generate new ones when the Generate quote button is submitted.

After some googling I can't seem to find an answer to why when clicking the generate quote button the JS loads and then seemingly breaks the page, creating an almost blink effect.

My desired outcome is to place both buttons inline next to each other and generate different events through their separate functions.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/dannyw24/pen/XWJjZxR)

Javascript code

```
//grab the id of the form
const quoteInputAdd = document.querySelector("#formHandle");
const quoteRetrieve = document.querySelector("#retrieveQuote");


//event when submit is clicked
quoteInputAdd.addEventListener("submit", quoteAdd);
quoteRetrieve.addEventListener("submit", generateQuote);

//set blank array.
quoteArr = [];
//create a blank quote arr to store the quotes in.
function quoteAdd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //get the value from the input
    const quoteText = document.querySelector("#quoteinputform").value;
    if (quoteText.length > 0) {
        //put the value at the end of the array
        quoteArr.push(quoteText);
        //add a successfully added quote message box and span
        let successBox = document.createElement("div");
        successBox.className = "alert alert-success";
        let spanBox = document.createElement("span");
        spanBox.className = "quoteMessage";
        let quoteString = document.createTextNode(quoteText + " was successfully added to the quote .");
        spanBox.appendChild(quoteString);
        successBox.appendChild(spanBox);
        let display = document.getElementById("main");
        display.appendChild(successBox);

    } else {
        alert("Please write something in the quote input field!");
    }

}

function generateQuote(e) {
    let quoteList = ["quotelistone", "quotelisttwo"];
    console.log(quoteList[0]);
    //test content
    let test = document.createElement("span");
    text = document.createTextNode("just some text");
    let main = document.getElementById("main");
    main.appendChild(text);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Quote Machine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-primary" id="main" role="alert">
          <form class="form-inline col-md-12" id="formHandle">

            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="quoteinputform" placeholder="Jane Doe">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add Quote</button>


          </form>
          <form class="form-inline col-md-12" id="retrieveQuote">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Generate Quote</button>
          </form>

          <div id="main">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code I believe its because I was missing  `e.preventDefault();` at the start of the second function.